# Support of facets in XSD in WCF 4

Tags: wcf

I've read that facets, restrictions in the xsd, are not supported by WCF.
But is there a way (custom code or something) to get it in the generated XSD.

I need my service to output something like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Amount_type">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:decimal">
        <xs:pattern value="-?\d{1,12}\.\d{2}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

I also need the minExclusive and maxEclusive facets in the output.

Can it be done?

Thanks,

Roland

Answer (score 0):

Like most things in .Net it can be done but I believe the amount of work would be inordinate. If you want this sort of control over the XSD you would be better taking a 'contract first' approach and using WCF with the XML serializer.